# How to capture frames from the Unity3d camera and display them on another rawImage in real time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rawimage

[image: the results]

I want to capture frames from Unity3d virtual camera and then let them displayed on another raw image.The result is that the raw image screen flickers very much.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RawImageVirtualWebCamTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RawImage rawimage;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("RawImageTransform");
        rawimage = obj.GetComponent<RawImage>();
    }

    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            rawimage.texture = source;
        }
        Graphics.Blit(source, destination);
    }
}
```

I want to see smooth pictures. But how to do that?

Answer (score 9):

If it is about a Unity `Camera` you don't have to capture anything.

Simply create a new [`RenderTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html)

`Assets` -> <kbd>right click</kbd> -> `Create` -> `RenderTexture`

[image]

let your `Camera` render into that `RenderTexture` instead of rendering the game view by simply referencing the created `RenderTexture` in `Target Texture` (that makes this `Camera` not render to the Game View anymore but to the referenced `RenderTexture`)

[image]

and finally simply use the created `RenderTexture` as `Texture` for the `RawImage`

[image]

---

If you need that `Camera` to render to the normal Game View at the same time simply use another `Camera` on a child object for the process above.

[image]

---

Result

[image]